# netcat, reopen TCP socket

Tags: linux, netcat

I have a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
    do
        nc -l -p 30003 | python3 script.py 
    done
```

I want that listening works all time.

```
nc localhost 30003 # works, fine
*type something*
Ctrl+C
```

Try again
`nc localhost 30003` # not working

So, after socket closed first time, it never open again..

How can I fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `-k` option with `nc`, it's in the [manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nc):

```
         -k' Forces nc to stay listening for another connection after its current connection is completed. It is an error to use this option without the -l option.
```

Comment: obvious RTFMaaS :)